# Fourier cosine transform

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Find Fourier cosine transform of $e^{-a^2 x^2}$ and hense evaluate Fourier sine transform of $x\cdot e^{-a^2x^2}$.

I can solve this question only if there is $x$ instead of $x^2$ in the exponential function $e^{-a^2x^2}$. Because in this situation i can use integral formula :- 
$$\int e^{-ax} \cos sx\,dx = \frac{e^{-ax}}{a^2+x^2} \left( s\sin sx-a\cos sx \right)$$
but what should i do if there is $x^2$ in exponential function $e$??

Comment: Please Learn TeX it will be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT 1:

$$
\int_{ - \infty }^\infty  {\cos (sx)e^{ - a^2 x^2 } \,{\rm d}x}  = \int_{ - \infty }^\infty  {[\cos (sx) + {\rm i}\sin (sx)]e^{ - a^2 x^2 } \,{\rm d}x}.
$$

HINT 2:

Characteristic function of the (centered) normal distribution: see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Characteristic_function_and_moment_generating_function).

**EDIT**: The first hints didn't help. So,

$$
\int_{ - \infty }^\infty  {\cos (sx)e^{ - a^2 x^2 } \,{\rm d}x}  = \int_{ - \infty }^\infty  {[\cos (sx) + {\rm i}\sin (sx)]e^{ - a^2 x^2 } \,{\rm d}x} = \int_{ - \infty }^\infty  {e^{{\rm i}sx} e^{ - a^2 x^2 } {\rm d}x} = ? 
$$
In order to calculate the right-most integral, bring it to the form(s) 
$$
b \int_{ - \infty }^\infty  {e^{ - a^2(x - {\rm i}c )^2  } \, {\rm d}x} = 
b \int_{ - \infty }^\infty  {e^{ - a^2 x^2 } \,{\rm d}x} = b' \int_{ - \infty }^\infty  {e^{ - x^2 } \,{\rm d}x} =...
$$

Comment: but, what should i do with real part  ∫e^(-a²x²).cos(sx)dx= ??

Comment: i mean there is standard formula for ⌠e^(-ax)cos(sx)dx = e^(-ax)/a²+x²[bsin(sx)-acos(sx)] but what?? for this integral ∫e^(-a²x²).cos(sx)dx= ??

Comment: @Lokesh: http://www.wolframalpha.com/. (The result involves error functions.)

Answer (score 2):

Find the Fourier transform of $e^{-a^2x^2}$. The real part of that is relevant to your cosine transform.

Comment: @Shai. While I was composing, I did not see your response.

Comment: Of course, I realized that.